# Button sending multiple request vs one single request

Tags: express, mongoose

My project allows for users to add comments to a post via a button and two things will happen.

1.Write a new `Comment` document to DB

2.Update the corresponding `Post` document with the new `Comment` document.

Here is a snippet of the `addPostComment` controller that handles both logic:

```
let newComment = new Comment({
      author: req.body.userId,
      content: req.body.content,
    });
    await newComment.save();
    existingPost.comments.push(newComment);
    await existingPost.save();
```

I have combined both logic into a single endpoint so that upon the button click, only one request will be sent.

Would it be better to create two separate endpoints i.e. One for solely creating a new `Comment` and another for updating the `Post` document? This means the button will send two request instead of one.

I don't think it makes a big difference for a small project but I wonder which is better for projects with more complexity.

Comment: What you have implemented is perfectly fine. You probably want to have error handling such that if a new comment fails to save you don't try to push to the existing post document. Similarly if the push fails you may or may not want to then go back and delete the comment.